# Tinymce: u.hasPlugin is not a function. (In 'u.hasPlugin("wordcount")', 'u.hasPlugin' is undefined)

Tags: asp.net-core, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I'm using TinyMCE 5.6.1 and I have an issue when I run the website from Safari (14.0.1). The following error is shown when I try to display a page with the TinyMCE control:

***TypeError: u.hasPlugin is not a function. (In 'u.hasPlugin("wordcount")', 'u.hasPlugin' is undefined)***

If I run the same site using Microsoft Edge or Google Chrome on my Mac then I have no issue.  This is an ASP.NET Core application.  If I run the application from the Visual Studio for Mac IDE which launches into Safari then it also works just fine without any errors.

I have the following at the top of the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

I then initialize the editor using the following:

```
<script>tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        menubar: false,
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table paste code help '
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | ' +
            'bold italic forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
            'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
            'removeformat | help',
        content_css: '//www.tiny.cloud/css/codepen.min.css'
    });</script>
```

Any thoughts as to what may be happening and how I can get this resolved?

I am using the following additional JS components:

```
@* ==============      JQUERY    ================== *@
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

@* ==============      BOOTSTRAP     ================== *@
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap-4.5.3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap-4.5.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>

@* ==============      DATATABLES     ================== *@
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/DataTables-1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/DataTables-1.10.22/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/Responsive-2.2.6/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/Responsive-2.2.6/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/datatables/RowGroup-1.1.2/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>

@* ==============      JQUERY VALIDATION     ================== *@
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Thanks.

--- Val

Comment: It may be caused by other JavaScript plugins conflicts, such as theme.js? Or do you use any other javascript plugins?

Comment: Hi @Karney.  Sorry for the delayed response.  I have updated the post to include the additional Javascript libraries I'm using.  They appear AFTER the TinyMCE declaration.

Comment: I just had this issue after upgrading to 5.6.2.  Turns out is was a cache issue.  Clear your cache and try again.

Comment: Thanks @BruceWells, that did the trick!